# Equivalent LINQ query for SQL query not resulting in expected results

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to write a LINQ query equivalent to below SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*,rm.RoleId FROM dbo.Menu m
INNER JOIN dbo.RoleMenu rm on m.Id=rm.MenuId
INNER JOIN dbo.RoleUser ru on rm.RoleId=ru.RoleId 
WHERE ru.UserName='dd@dd.com' and m.Url='/dashboard#/pm'
```

I came with the below query which is not returning the expected output

```
var auth = _context.RoleUsers.Where(
    x => x.Role.MenuRoles.FirstOrDefault().Menu.Url == pagePermissions.Url 
         && x.UserName == pagePermissions.UserName).Count()
```

**May I know a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sql looks at all the menus related to a role user, but your Linq is only looking at the first one.  I think you want `x.Role.MenuRoles.Any(mr => mr.Menu.Url == pagePermissions.Url)`.  But then you're also doing a `Count` on the matching users instead of selecting the menus that match that url.  A closer translation would be.

```
var results = (from m in _context.Menus
               from rm in m.RoleMenus
               from ru in rm.RoleUsers
               where m.Url == pagePermissions.Url
                     && u.UserName == pagePermissions.UserName
               select new { Menu = m, rm.RoleId }).Distinct();
```

You may have to adjust some of the navigation properties as I was just guessing at them.  They usually are pluralizations of the tables, but I see in your Linq that you have `MenuRoles` instead of `RoleMenus`.